# how to interpret the PIL image in numpy array

Tags: numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to understand the output of image conversion in to numPy

```
im = Image.open('flower1.jpg')
npimg = np.array(im)
npimg
```

output

```
([[[127, 151,  89],
        [125, 149,  87],
        [125, 149,  87],
        ..., 
        [117, 142,  76],
        [115, 141,  73],
        [113, 140,  71]],...
```

I don't know what to understand from this output? Can someone help?

Comment: It's explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52113846/2836621

Answer (score 4):

The printed value is:

```
([[[127, 151,  89],
 ^ a list of rows
  ^ where each row is a list of pixels
   ^ where each pixel is a list of values that correspond to RGB
     (or RGBA, or L, etc... depending on the image format)
```

You can see the shape of a numpy array by accessing the `.shape` member.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the below image. 
[image]

In the magnified version, an image is many pixels of colors arranged in rows and columns. Each point or pixel in the image is an array of red, blue and green channel.

If you try, `npimg.shape` you would get 3 number set something like `(500,600,3)`, which means there are 500 rows, 600 columns and 3 colors in each pixel in your image.

Answer (score 0):

It's an nxmx3 array where nxm is the resolution of the image and the 3 are the red green blue color channels. The datatype is uint8: values range between 0 and 255 at each color channel.